# Two different remainders for same expression

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$\frac{n! + 1}{n} = (n-1)! + \frac{1}{n}$$
The remainder is $\frac{1}{n}$

$$n! + 1 \equiv 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \dotsc (n-1) \cdot 0 + 1 \equiv 1 \mod n$$
The remainder is $1$

What is going on? Why am I getting two different remainders for the same operation?

Comment: Well in the first equation the remainder is $1$ too. You don't divide the remainder by $n$.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve just said the same thing in two different ways. The reason that they seem to say something different is that you’re conflating *remainder* with *fractional part of quotient*.

Your first equation says that $n!+1=n\cdot(n-1)!+1$; to see this, just multiply it by $n$. This says that the remainder when you divide $n!+1$ by $n$ is $1$, just as your second result does.

Alternatively, recall that the statement that $n!+1\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ means that there is some integer $q$ such that $(n!+1)-1=qn$; if you now divide this through by $n$ and rearrange it a little, you get

$$\frac{n!+1}n=q+\frac1n\;.$$

Of course the $q$ here is $(n-1)!$.

More generally, when you divide $n$ by $d$ to get a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$, it’s always true that $n=dq+r$, so

$$\frac{n}d=q+\frac{r}d\;:$$

the fractional part of the quotient is the remainder $r$ divided by the divisor $d$.